# Is there a Daily/Alpha/Beta Bug Report Applet/Widget?

Tags: software-recommendation, bug-reporting

I'm looking for an applet on daily/alpha/beta builds on the bar that you could click and then click on an application that's causing issues and then write your report. It would make life so much easier, and also allow many new users to have a nicer bug reporting experience.

It would also be nice if the same applet/widget click just be used to also just start up a blank bug report window too.

That, or something like the "Feedback" button found in firefox, but globally available for the distro. Or something like what Microsoft do with their beta applications, with a button in the taskbar or in the top of the application window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great deal of applications have a Help -> Report a Problem menu entry that does just this.

Answer (score 2):

I know of no such applet, but in pre-release distributions apport crash collecting is already active, which lets you report a bug with ease by collecting all the technical details for you. You can trigger it manually too:

```
ubuntu-bug unity
```

...will have apport collect information about the Ubuntu package `unity`, then start the bug reporting process for you.